# How do I fix an error in my word problem solver algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am trying to create an algorithm that solves word problems

```
'' import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.lang.*;
   public abstract class test {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void check() throws IOException {
    String q = s.nextLine();

    
    boolean add[] = {q.contains("together"), q.contains("sum"), q.contains("more"),q.contains("plus"), q.contains("altogether")};
    
    if (add[0] == true || add[1] == true || add[3] == true || add[4] == true|| add[2] == true) {
        
        
        String[] split = {"and",",",".","more"};
        
        
    
        String[] parsedLine[] = {q.split(split[0]),q.split(split[1]),q.split(split[2]),q.split(split[3])};
        
         
        String[] num1 = {parsedLine[0][0],parsedLine[0][1],parsedLine[0][2],parsedLine[0][3]};
        
        String[] num2 = {parsedLine[1][0],parsedLine[1][1],parsedLine[1][2],parsedLine[1][3]};
        
        
        
        int numget1[] = {Integer.parseInt(num1[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")),Integer.parseInt(num1[1].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")),Integer.parseInt(num1[2].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")),Integer.parseInt(num1[3].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))};
        int numget2[] = {Integer.parseInt(num2[0].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")),Integer.parseInt(num2[1].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")),Integer.parseInt(num2[2].replaceAll("[\\D]", "")),Integer.parseInt(num2[3].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))};
        
        int res[] = {numget1[0] + numget2[0],numget1[1] + numget2[1],numget1[2] + numget2[2],numget1[3] + numget2[3]};
        
        
        
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    
    String question = "if ben has 3 apples and bee has 4 apples how many apples do they have all together";

    check();


}}
```

I want this algorithm solve this simple world problem "if ben has 3 apples and bee has 4 apples how many apples do they have all together?"

basically it checks if its addition if it is it splits it removes the string turns it into int then adds the int simple but I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at mathproblemsolving.test.check(test.java:34)
    at mathproblemsolving.test.main(test.java:61)
```

Comment: Regex is not the way to do this.  I'd recommend a lexer/parser with a grammar.  Not easy.

Answer (score 1):

String#split takes a regular expression as argument. The "." is the regular expression for "any character", so that `"Some.String".split(".")` will return an empty array.

You need to escape the ".", that is `"Some.String".split("\\.")` will return the desired result.

You can view more information regarding `split()` here: [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

More information on Regex Expression here: [W3 java_regex](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp)

Comment: what does \\n mean?

Comment: @EnzoSebastian, that was a typo, thanks for pointing out. I corrected it to \\.